# How to Deactive Injected ViewModel into ContentControl

Tags: caliburn.micro

How to Deactive Injected ViewModel into ContentControl

```
[Import]
public IMyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }

public void ClickButton
{
   //This Method Not Deactive MyViewModel
   MyViewModel.Deactivate(true);
}

<ContentControl x:Name="MyViewModel" />
```

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't remove it from a conductor? You need to activate items via a conductor to have them obey proper lifecycle - can you show the XAML for the page too? Calling deactivate won't close the VM if the VM isn't conducted by anything

Comment: Why are you deactivating a view model explictly? As Charleh says, the reason is because the view model isn't being conducted.

Comment: I've put a load of info about conductors and screens into my answer on your other post, Alex. It also links to the CM documentation on these (which is very good with lots of examples): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055955/caliburn-micro-navigation-with-mainmenu-and-submenu/16058209#16058209

Comment: Thanks Charleh & devdigital solved my problem.